# ranking similarity of one vector with a very large dataframe of vectors in panda

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sklearn-pandas, cosine-similarity

Objective: I'm trying to create an ordered list of items that are ranked based on how close they are with a test item.

I have 1 test item with 10 attributes and 250,000 items with 10 attributes. I want a list that ranks the 250,000 items. For example, if the resulting list came back [10,50,21,11,10000....] than the item with index 10 would be closest to my test item, index 50 is second closest to my test item, etc.

**What I have tried works for small dataframes but not larger dataframes:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

similarity_matrix = pd.np.random.rand(4,4) 

#4 items with the first being the test
#0.727048   0.113704    0.886672    0.0345438
#0.496636   0.678949    0.0627973   0.547752
#0.641021   0.498811    0.628728    0.575058
#0.760778   0.955595    0.646792    0.126714 

#creates the cosine similarity matrix 
winner = cosine_similarity(similarity_matrix) 

#I just need the first row, how similar each item is to the test, I'm excluding how similar the test is to the test 
winner = np.argsort(winner[0:1,1:])

#I want to reverse the order and add one so the list matches the original index    
winner = np.flip(winner) +1
```

Unfortunately, with 250,000 I get the following error "MemoryError: Unable to allocate 339. GiB for an array with shape (250000, 250000) and data type float64"

Instead of creating a 250000X250000 matrix I really only need the first row.  Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call cosine_similarity with a second argument it will only compute the distance against the second array.
An example with random vectors

```
x = np.random.rand(5,2)
```

With one argument

```
cosine_similarity(x)
array([[1.        , 0.95278802, 0.93496787, 0.45860786, 0.62841819],
       [0.95278802, 1.        , 0.99853581, 0.70677904, 0.8349406 ],
       [0.93496787, 0.99853581, 1.        , 0.74401257, 0.86348853],
       [0.45860786, 0.70677904, 0.74401257, 1.        , 0.979448  ],
       [0.62841819, 0.8349406 , 0.86348853, 0.979448  , 1.        ]])
```

With the first vector as second argument

```
cosine_similarity(x, [x[0]])
array([[1.        ],
       [0.95278802],
       [0.93496787],
       [0.45860786],
       [0.62841819]])
```

---

If you're still running out of memory you can compute the distance in chunks

```
chunks = 4
np.concatenate(
    [cosine_similarity(i, [x[0]]) for i in np.array_split(x, chunks)]
)
array([[1.        ],
       [0.95278802],
       [0.93496787],
       [0.45860786],
       [0.62841819]])
```

Comment: Your answer worked when I set the df to a np.array. For completeness exporting the list afterwards requires the following changes:  `winner = cosine_similarity(np_array,[np_array[0]])[1:,:] #take all elements except the first
winner = winner[:,0].argsort(axis=0) #sort the index of the array
winner = np.flip(winner) +1 #flip the sort order and add one to match the index`

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the distance row by row
eg.

```py
test = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
big_matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]])

#calculate and concat all of them into one
result = np.array([cosine_similarity(test, row.reshape(1, -1)) for row in big_matrix]).reshape(-1, 1)
winner = np.argsort(result)
```

Comment: This seems promising, but returns an error "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:  array=[1. 2. 3.]."

Comment: This does not work, the result is 0 0  and it should be 1 0 in this example.  I think the issue is that the test array should be appended to the row.  I'm not sure how to do it in a list comprehension, but over multiple lines it would look closer to this `array1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
array2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
array3 = np.append(array1,array2, axis=0)
cosine_similarity(array3)[0,1]`